# Android Open Activity Multiple Times from Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

When clicking my notification, it opens the activity once and works fine, but then the notification remains in the message tray and doesn't open anything again.

Is there a way to set up the notification to open the activity every time the user clicks on it? Or is this not feasible with Android?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

try to put launch mode to activity which you are trying to open from notification.Link will provide description about **launch mode**

```
<activity
android:name=".SingleTaskActivity"
android:label="singleTask launchMode"
android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

[Helpful link for Launch mode](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)